# Building FLOAT64 out of the FLOAT32 IEEE 754 hex representation in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to build a FLOAT64 out of a FLOAT32 IEEE 754 hex representation in Bigquery.

Here's what I've done so far. Is there a better performing, more integrated, safer alternative?

```
WITH
  T1 AS (
  SELECT
    0x443dd04f float32_repr -- hex repr of 759.25482177734375
    ),
  T2 AS (
  SELECT
  IF (float32_repr>> 31=0, 1, -1) my_sign,
  (float32_repr& 0x7f800000) >> 23 my_exponent,
  float32_repr& 0x007fffff my_mantissa,
  FROM
    T1 )
SELECT
  my_sign*POW(2,my_exponent- 127)* (1+my_mantissa/(1<<23)) my_value
FROM
  T2
-- returns 759.25482177734375
```

I would also like to know how to do it for FLOAT16 and FLOAT64 representations.

Answer (score 2):

Using the javascript implementation on below link, I think you can define BigQuery UDF and parse FLOAT32 IEEE 754 hex representation by using it.

- https://gist.github.com/laerciobernardo/498f7ba1c269208799498ea8805d8c30

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION parseFloat(str STRING) RETURNS FLOAT64
LANGUAGE js AS r"""
  var float = 0, sign, order, mantiss,exp,
      int = 0, multi = 1;
  if (/^0x/.exec(str)) {
    int = parseInt(str,16);
  }else{
    for (var i = str.length -1; i >=0; i -= 1) {
      if (str.charCodeAt(i)>255) {
        console.log('Wrong string parametr'); 
        return false;
      }
      int += str.charCodeAt(i) * multi;
      multi *= 256;
    }
  }
  sign = (int>>>31)?-1:1;
  exp = (int >>> 23 & 0xff) - 127;
  mantissa = ((int & 0x7fffff) + 0x800000).toString(2);
  for (i=0; i<mantissa.length; i+=1){
    float += parseInt(mantissa[i])? Math.pow(2,exp):0;
    exp--;
  }
  return float*sign;
""";

SELECT parseFloat('0x443dd04f');
```

```
+-----+--------------------+
| Row |        f0_         |
+-----+--------------------+
|   1 | 759.25482177734375 |
+-----+--------------------+
```